# djangofilterbackend query params and un populated query param options

Tags: python, django, filtering, django-filter

I want to create viewset in django which will take a url with query params and filter upon the query params. My biggest problem with documentation is it doesn't idiot proof them. Take this example from the django rest framework docs http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

```
class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):
queryset = Product.objects.all()
serializer_class = ProductSerializer
filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
filter_fields = ('category', 'in_stock')
```

which will work with the below url:

http://example.com/api/products?category=clothing&in_stock=True

but what if I have a url without the category option set for example. Will this code break? Or is it smart enough to know when a query param filter isn't populated and ignore it?

If it isn't then I would imagine I have to create a filter like this:

```
ass PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Optionally restricts the returned purchases to a given user,
    by filtering against a `username` query parameter in the URL.
    """
    queryset = Purchase.objects.all()
    username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)
    if username is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(purchaser__username=username)
    return queryset
```

Which ok fine, but does that mean that djangofilterbackend library is only good for use cases where filters are guarnteed? If not can someone please provide me an example, since the docs don't realize im stupid as hell.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django filter is a very powerful library that makes filtering and searching really easy. The example you provided is from the [django filter docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/guide/rest_framework.html) which explains clearly the usage of filter in viewsets.

As the question points, the filter works clearly on

[http://example.com/api/products?category=clothing&in_stock=True](http://example.com/api/products/)

This url gives the list of products filtered with category- clothing and stock-True.

But if you do not provide the query params specified in `filter_fields` like

http://example.com/api/products/

Then this gives the list of products without applying any filtering, thus, it is not necessary to provide query params in the url if no filtering needs to be applied.

So urls:

```
http://example.com/api/products?category=&in_stock=

and 

http://example.com/api/products/
```

**both gives the same result.**

It also works when only one filter should be applied.
So urls

```
http://example.com/api/products?category=clothing

and 

http://example.com/api/products?category=clothing&in_stock=
```

**both give same results**

Finally, custom queryset can be build that applies the filter parameter before customizing the queryset like

```
def my_new_queryset(self):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    // customize queryset 
    ...
```

Or, simply override `filter_queryset` method for generic filtering.
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#custom-generic-filtering

Comment: thanks man but your answer is  confusing. Will setting a filter with djangofilterbackend allow for urls where no query params are present or only one query  param present even if there are filters for say 5? What I mean in is can I use djagnofilterbackend as the example shown in the djangobackend docs with dynamic use of the query params? As in no guarntee that all query params will be there?

Comment: Yes it allows for urls with no query params present. As shown in the example it makes no difference. Query params will work if value is present otherwise not

Comment: ok then its safe to infer that it also allows for some but not all query params present correct?